# How to generate the following $n$-level $n$-particle singlet state?

Tags: circuit-construction

Could you please give a direction/reference towards realising the following using any set of realisable quantum gates

$$\boxed{|S_{n}\rangle = \frac{1} {\sqrt{n!}} \sum_{S\in P_n^{n}} ( \,-1) \,^{\Gamma(S)}|s_{0}\rangle |s_{1}\rangle ....|s_{n-1}\rangle}$$

Here $P_n^{n}$ is the set of all permutations of $Z_n := \{0,1,··· ,n−1\}$, $S$ is a permutation (or sequence) in the form $S = s_0 s_1 ···s_{n−1}$. $\Gamma(S)$, named inverse number, is defined as the number of transpositions of pairs of elements of $S$ that must be composed to place the elements in canonical order, $012 · · · n−1$.

Comment: It is an interesting question. May I ask what does the state represent?

Comment: @MartinVesely The state enumerates all permutations of $Z_{n}$. I don't know the significance of inverse number here.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8976/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/9022/55

Comment: just want to point out that "*any set of realisable quantum gates*" is not a sensible requirement, otherwise I can just answer this by saying "*use any gate that sends $|0\cdots 0\rangle$ to $|S_n\rangle$*", which is a realisable quantum gate (any gate is "realisable"). You are probably thinking of using as "realisable quantum gates" single-qubit gates and CNOTs, or something similar

Comment: I just realised that this question is an exact duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8668/55